# Cannot execute a setter in a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, state

I'm trying to write a hero quest type script.

In which we browse an array of events. Either the player moves, or he faces an enemy and a fight begins.

So I wrote my script. The quest and read well from start to finish.

Then, I said to myself, that before going any further I was going to do a test where in the first fight the hero's life bridges drop to zero to test the game over situation.

So in the fightHandle function I drop my hero's life points to zero.

But in my loop, this is not taken into account and the hero's life points constantly remain at 10 points while during the quest he passes X through the combat phase.

I did a lot of tests, but I do not see where my error is something escapes me ...

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { character } from "./assets/character/character";

export default function Quest({ quest }) {
  const [player, setPlayer] = useState(character.player);

  const startQuest = (quest) => {
    const nbAction = quest.action.length;

    let i = 1;
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      let action = quest.action[i];

      console.log("Life point", player.life);

      if (player.life > 0) {
        if (i === nbAction) {
          clearInterval(timer);
          endQuest();
        } else {
          if (action === "move") {
            console.log("player movement");
          } else {
            eventHandler(action);
          }
        }
      } else {
        console.log("GAME OVER");
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
      i++;
    }, 500);
  };

  const eventHandler = (action) => {
    console.log(`Interaction with the element: ${action}`);

    const eventType = character[action].type;

    if (eventType === "statiqueMonster" || eventType === "monster") {
      const eventResolution = fightHandle(player, action);

      if (eventResolution === false) {
        console.log("GAME OVER");
      }
    }
  };

  const fightHandle = (player, action) => {
    console.log("!!!!!!!---FIGHT---!!!!!!!");
    setPlayer((s) => ({ ...s, life: 0 })); 

    if (player.life === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  };

  const endQuest = () => {
    console.log(player);
    console.log("fin de la quête", quest.name);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    startQuest(quest);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Quest</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: and `fightHandle` is being called?

Comment: add this log: `useEffect(() => console.log({player}), [player]);` and tell me if `player` gets updated or not.

Comment: @hellogoodnight, yes it well called.
And in the useeffect the player is not modified :(

Comment: can you comment out `if (player.life === 0) { return false; }` and see if you get same behaviour?

Comment: Inside `fightHandle`

Comment: Yes it happens exactly the same.

What is strange is that eg.

I run my script, I watch it run in the console. Things are unfolding as I described them.

I modify a character in my code, I save, the hot reload relaunches the script and it starts with zero life points. What to go crazy ^^

Comment: Can you put the body of startQuest inside of the useEffect that starts it instead?

Comment: So remove the actual funtion and put the functionality in the useEffect that runs on first render.

Comment: Uh wait, now in the useffect, the player's life points are at zero, but the loop does not end for all that and does not go to game over. I have nothing to modify yet. ^^

However the script goes to the endQuest function, and there the life points are at 10 ....

Comment: nothing changes

Comment: aha ok, so that was what I guessed. give me a sec

Comment: I added an answer, try it and see if it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use useRef instead:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { character } from "./assets/character/character";

export default function Quest({ quest }) {
  //const [player, setPlayer] = useState(character.player);

  const playerRef = useRef(character.player);

  const startQuest = (quest) => {
    const nbAction = quest.action.length;

    let i = 1;
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      let action = quest.action[i];

      console.log("Life point", player.life);

      if (playerRef.current.life > 0) {
        if (i === nbAction) {
          clearInterval(timer);
          endQuest();
        } else {
          if (action === "move") {
            console.log("player movement");
          } else {
            eventHandler(action);
          }
        }
      } else {
        console.log("GAME OVER");
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
      i++;
    }, 500);
  };

  const eventHandler = (action) => {
    console.log(`Interaction with the element: ${action}`);

    const eventType = character[action].type;

    if (eventType === "statiqueMonster" || eventType === "monster") {
      const eventResolution = fightHandle(player, action);

      if (eventResolution === false) {
        console.log("GAME OVER");
      }
    }
  };

  const fightHandle = (player, action) => {
    console.log("!!!!!!!---FIGHT---!!!!!!!");
    //setPlayer((s) => ({ ...s, life: 0 })); 
    playerRef.current = {...playerRef.current, life: 0};
    if (player.life === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  };

  const endQuest = () => {
    console.log(player);
    console.log("fin de la quête", quest.name);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    startQuest(quest);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Quest</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ok it works, you are my hero.

But why does it work with refs and not with usestate? I do not understand .

Comment: When setTimeout is scheduled it's using the value of count at the time it was scheduled. It's relying on a closure to access count asynchronously. When the component re-renders a new closure is created but that doesn't change the value that was initially closed over.

Comment: I got that from internet, lol :D

Comment: I knew it but couldn't really explain it well.

Comment: Ok good! And,  if I used  useMemo on the startQuest function can be that it would work with the state ??

Comment: In fact, no! lol...